# How to speed up auto complete code in MySQl workbench when typing without using ctrl + space

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

When typing in MySQL Workbench, it takes a long time to show the autocomplete code suggestion. I have to pause for a while to wait for the autocomplete box to show up. Is there any way to make the suggestion appear faster without using ctrl + space???